# Проблема с ActionBar

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, не могу сделать `ActionBar`, чтобы при нажатии на иконку приложения возвращало на предыдущую `Activity`. При компиляции приложения и его запуске стрелочка у иконки появляется, но при нажатии приложение вылетает. Должно с `FirstActivity` перекидывать на `HomeActivity`. Но почему то виснет и вылетает. Вот как у меня:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entry);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял,

> На предыдущую активити

значит, что из **HomeActivity** Вы запустили **FirstActivity**. Тогда замените

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

на **finish();**

Comment: Так она просто закрывает приложение.

Comment: Все решил сам ) Оказываться проблема была связана с HomeActivity

Comment: Сам это хорошо. Закрепляет понимание :)